# How to cancel ros2 action with ros2 cpp action client

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pleas provide ros2 cpp example client to cancel actions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397310/how-to-cancel-ros2-action-with-ros2-cpp-action-client/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2022-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you wish https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/643bb0f4912494389be580763784203ec60aeb39/nav2_behavior_tree/include/nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp#L280-L287

```
  auto future_cancel = action_client_->async_cancel_goal(goal_handle_);
  if (callback_group_executor_.spin_until_future_complete(future_cancel, server_timeout_) !=
    rclcpp::FutureReturnCode::SUCCESS)
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(
      node_->get_logger(),
      "Failed to cancel action server for %s", action_name_.c_str());
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2022-09-07**:
I think there is something weird around. According with your code we need the goal_handle_ to cancel the action. Ok, sounds good. But it  turns out that you get that goal_handle_ value only after the future of the response of the original request is resolved.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/643bb0f4912494389be580763784203ec60aeb39/nav2_behavior_tree/include/nav2_behavior_tree/bt_action_node.hpp#L377